# Unit tests of Hibernate based code on top of hsqldb 1.8.1.3 no longer work on hsqldb 2.2.9

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

I frequently write unit tests of my database dependent code using an in-memory HSQL database as the testing database.  Recently I decided to upgrade from 1.8.1.3 to 2.2.9 to take advantage of ROW_NUMBER() support that was added in the 2.x release branch.

It seems that in some way, the new version is more strict than the old version.  Using Hibernate (3.6.10) as the ORM, I might for example create a `Configuration` object to create a first `SessionFactory`, use that to populate the test data, then uses the `Configuration` to the class under test, which creates it's own `SessionFactory` to do a select.  With hsqldb 1.8.1.3, no problem.  With 2.2.9, the select blocks inside of hsqldb code.  Below is a SSCCE demonstrating this:

```
public void testTwoSessionFactories() throws Exception {
    boolean withTx = false;

    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().addAnnotatedClass(Entity.class);
    config.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, HSQLDialect.class.getName());
    config.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, jdbcDriver.class.getName());
    config.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB");
    config.setProperty(Environment.USER, "SA");
    config.setProperty(Environment.PASS, "");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory1.openSession();

    Transaction tx = null;
    if (withTx)
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(new Entity("one"));

    if (withTx)
        tx.commit();

    session.flush();
    session.close();

    config.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session2 = sessionFactory2.openSession();
    List entities = session2.createCriteria(Entity.class).list();
    session2.close();
}
```

Note the `withTx` boolean.  With HSQLDB 1.8.1.3, I can run this code with `withTx` true or false, and it'll be fine.  With HSQLDB 2.2.9, `withTx` *must be set to true*, otherwise the thread gets blocked in the `.list()` call with the following stack:

```
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.park(Object) line: not available    
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).parkAndCheckInterrupt() line: not available 
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: not available   
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: not available 
CountDownLatch.await() line: not available  
CountUpDownLatch.await() line: not available    
Session.executeCompiledStatement(Statement, Object[]) line: not available   
Session.execute(Result) line: not available 
JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult() line: not available 
JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery() line: not available    
BatchingBatcher(AbstractBatcher).getResultSet(PreparedStatement) line: 208  
CriteriaLoader(Loader).getResultSet(PreparedStatement, boolean, boolean, RowSelection, SessionImplementor) line: 1953   
CriteriaLoader(Loader).doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 802  
CriteriaLoader(Loader).doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 274   
CriteriaLoader(Loader).doList(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 2542   
CriteriaLoader(Loader).listIgnoreQueryCache(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) line: 2276 
CriteriaLoader(Loader).list(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, Set, Type[]) line: 2271    
CriteriaLoader.list(SessionImplementor) line: 119   
SessionImpl.list(CriteriaImpl) line: 1716   
CriteriaImpl.list() line: 347   
EntityTest.testTwoSessionFactories() line: 46
```

What changed in HSQLDB between 1.8.1.3 and 2.2.9 that requires this code to do the save within a transaction, and can I turn it off?

Comment: Every database interaction should be done inside a transaction anyway. That's what the Hibernate documentation recommends. I'd simply fix the bug and make sure you always use transactions. Also, why are you using two different session factories? There's no reason to do that. A session factory is a heavyweight object that should be created once and for all. +1 for the clear unit test.

Comment: @JBNizet Re: transactions, in production code I do always do that, but in test set up code I'm looser because I think it just adds clutter to the test.  Not so bad that I can't change it though!

Comment: @JBNizet Re: session factories, because the class under test (in this case) is responsible for creating and keeping the session factory.  The first session factory is to set up the test data.  In other situations, the class under test takes a Session or is given a SessionFactory, and then there's only one SessionFactory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HSQLDB 1.8.x` uses `READ UNCOMMITTED` for rows that have been added or changed by another transaction.

`HSQLDB 2.x` uses `READ COMMITTED` (by default) or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. Therefore a transaction must commit before its changes are visible. There is also the `transaction model` to consider.

The default `transaction model` is `LOCKS` which locks a table that is modified until the transaction is committed. You can use the `MVCC model` instead, which allows other sessions to read from the table and to modify rows that have not been modified. You can use this model with a `URL property`.

```
config.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB;hsqldb.tx=mvcc");
```

Comment: That sounds like it, I'll check it out.  Any way to change a property so that I can change to READ UNCOMMITTED at the connection pool level?

Comment: READ UNCOMMITTED is not supported in newer versions.

Comment: Got it, I was relying on the dirty read 'feature' that they talk about in [the docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sessions-chapt.html#snc_tx_tx_cc).  I'll change to use explicit transactions in my test, thanks for showing me the way!