# How to set transaction isolation level with DBUnit

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, guice, dbunit

I have a simple transaction isolation test below which works as expected if I run against my SQLServer DB, but hangs when I run using DBUnit.

```
@Test
@com.google.inject.persist.Transactional
public void testFreeze() {
  try {
    EntityManager applicationManagedEntityManager = entityMangerFactoryProvider.get().createEntityManager();
    EntityManager guiceManagedEntityManager = entityManager.get();

    Person p = new Person("Fred");
    guiceManagedEntityManager.persist(p);//But not committed
    guiceManagedEntityManager.flush();//* Note

    runQuery(guiceManagedEntityManager, "select count(*) from Person");//Works just fine
    runQuery(applicationManagedEntityManager, "select count(*) from Person");//Hangs when running this query using DBUnit
    applicationManagedEntityManager.close();
  }
  catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private void runQuery(final EntityManager entityManager, final String query) {
  entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
  //Or try running it as below
  //Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
  //session.doWork(new Work() {
  //  @Override
  //  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
  //    connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
  //    entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery(query).uniqueResult();
  //  }
  //});
}
```

Note  : I have an artificial flush here to simulate what might (and does) happen in reality. Running further queries on "person" may cause a flush.

SQL Server performs as expected. Setting READ_COMMIT on either the persistence.xml ("hibernate.connection.isolation" set to "1") OR changing it on the fly for that connection as in the commented out code, the test completes. However running the same test against DBUnit hangs in all cases. Is this a DBUnit bug, or is there a setting I dont know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually related to HSQLDB (2.3.2). It does not support READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction isolation level. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108643/unit-tests-of-hibernate-based-code-on-top-of-hsqldb-1-8-1-3-no-longer-work-on-hs) here provides further details.